# What is $\int f d\mu$ where $\mu$ is discrete?

Tags: real-analysis

What is $\int f d\mu$ where $\mu$ is discrete?

Or rather, *why* is it $\sum f(k) \mu(k)$?

Comment: Assuming $k$ is an integer, that's only true when $\mu$ is discrete **and** supported on $\mathbb Z$. More generally, the form would be $\sum f(x_k)\mu(x_k)$.

Comment: It is a subtle integral. (Sorry, bad pun.)

Comment: You need to look at how integration is defined using simple functions for non negative functions. For a simple function $\sum_k \alpha_k 1_{A_k}$ the integral is defined as $\sum_k \alpha_k \mu(A_k)$. If the measure is discrete, then you only need to 'worry' about where $\mu$ is non zero.

Comment: Is the measure supported on the integers?

Comment: I think this question needs more context, like what definition for $\int f \mathrm{d} \mu $ is being used. Or even lack thereof, and maybe asking for an intuitive answer etc. etc.

Answer (score 2):

... because that is clearly true for the case when $f $ is zero except for one point.

Comment: It took geniuses many years to even properly define what the hell $\int f d \mu$ even means ... but I guess if you say so, it must be "clear". What a bunch of idiots those guys were ,amiright?

Comment: @SunWukong It's clear because in that case $f$ is a simple function, so the equality is true *by definition*.

Comment: $f$ is not a simple function. I did not ask him to answer that special case.

Comment: That special case plus the monotone convergence theorem is all you need.

Comment: And what is the monotone convergence theorem? Guess it wasn't "clearly true" after all ... How about you stop assuming everybody knows what you do?

Comment: @SunWukong Ask a question without context, and get an answer without context...

Comment: @Bungo How can I provide the context of "I do not know what the monotone theorem is" when I don't bloody know it? Are you kidding me? All the necessary context is there. It is YOU who needs to stop assuming I know what some fancy convergence theorem is.

Comment: @SunWukong It's one of the first theorems discussed in integration theory; since you provided no context **at all**, it was not unreasonable to assume that you were aware of it.

Comment: @Bungo I did not say it was unreasonable to assume it, I said that it is not a "clearly true" type of situation, and you implying that it is, is what the issue is here. What's the point in saying that something is clearly true, when it necessitates the knowledge of a theorem which is not even mentioned in the answer by Hagen Von Eitzen? If he mentioned it, I would look it up. But his answer as currently stated is not only incomplete, it is misleading.

Comment: Also, upon reading on wikipedia on the montone convergence theorem, it still eludes me why it is "clear" that $\int f d \mu = \sum f(k) \mu(k)$. Maybe I am just a complete idiot, but considering how great I am at other math problems, I am pretty sure the problem isn't me, but you and your inability to differentiate between "clearly true **to me**" and "clearly true *for everybody else*".

Comment: @SunWukong Your question had absolutely no context.  You gave no indication of whether you saw this notation in a paper you were reading or some coursework you are taking, or Wikipedia.  You gave no indication of what mathematical experience you have: are you studying measure theory or first-year probability (which uses discrete distributions without defining what it means for a general measure to be discrete)?  You gave no context for why you think those two quantities are equal; you gave no context for anything and your belligerence is utterly misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

First suppose $f \ge 0$, then we define
$\int f d \mu = \sup \{ \int s d \mu | 0 \le s \le f, s \text{ simple} \}$,
where
$\int \sum_k \alpha_k 1_{A_k} d \mu = \sum_k \alpha_k \mu A_k $. Then
for general $f$ we define $\int f d \mu = \int \max(0,f) d \mu - \int \max(0,-f) d \mu$.

Since $\mu$ is discrete, we have some at most countable collection $x_k$ on which $\mu$ is concentrated and
$\mu A = \sum_{ \{ k | x_k \in A \}} \mu \{x_k\}$.

Suppose $s$ is simple with $0 \le s \le f$. Let $s=\sum_k \alpha_k 1_{A_k}$ and without loss of generality we can assume the $A_k$ are
pairwise disjoint.

If $x \in A_k$, then since $s(x) \le f(x)$ we have $\alpha_k \le \inf_{x\in A_k} f(x)$ and so
\begin{eqnarray}
\int s d \mu &=& \sum_k \alpha_k \mu A_k  \\
&\le& \sum_k ( \inf_{x\in A_k} f(x) ) \mu A_k \\
&=& \sum_k ( \inf_{x\in A_k} f(x) ) \sum_{ \{ j | x_j \in A_k \}} \mu \{x_j\} \\
&=& \sum_k  \sum_{ \{ j | x_j \in A_k \}} ( \inf_{x\in A_k} f(x) ) \mu \{x_j\} \\
&\le& \sum_k  \sum_{ \{ j | x_j \in A_k \}} f(x_j) \mu \{x_j\} \\
&\le& \sum_j f(x_j) \mu \{x_j\} \\
\end{eqnarray}
Furthermore, by taking $s_n = \sum_{j \le n} f(x_j) 1_{\{x_j\}}$ we 
see that $\int s_n d \mu \to \sum_j f(x_j) \mu \{x_j\}$, hence
$\int f d \mu = \sum_j f(x_j) \mu \{x_j\}$.