# If $P$ is a discrete measure, what does it mean to say $\int f dP$ where $f$ is not discrete?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $f$ be a function from the reals to the reals. Let $m$ be any discrete measure on the integers.

I am interested in $\int f dP$. I know if $f$ is defined on the integers, then it ist just $\sum f(k) P(k)$ over all integers, but what if $f$ is a map from  and to $\mathbb{R}$?

Is the answer still the same? Is this well-defined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is $\int f d\mu$ where $\mu$ is discrete?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475392/what-is-int-f-d-mu-where-mu-is-discrete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the same. To see this, just go back to the definition of the integral w.r.t a given measure.